# Does a mobile app need to poll external data sources or can it receive data in other ways?

Tags: architecture, programming-practices, mobile

I'm beginning the design stages of a mobile application. I'm looking for knowledge about common practices for user notifications. I understand that the SDK for the device will expose methods which will allow me to notify a user how and when I need it to. What I'm not sure about is how my application gets notified from a external data source. Is it common practice to poll a web service for data periodically? Or is it more likely that my application will have the facility to receive data at any time?

For example:
I have a website which asks users to fill out a contact form. I would like my mobile app to display a notification when one of these forms gets filled out. Should my app be polling my data server for updated records or should my site be notifying my app somehow of a new record?

Any opinions or advice are welcomed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This will most likely depend on whether your target platform/device support [server push](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology). Not all of them do.

Also it is worth keeping in mind that even in some cases when it's supported, end user may have an option to turn it off.

- Given above, I'd consider "push-only" application only when I am certain that it is established as a major feature at target platform. I mean if say, I know that 9 of 10 applications will fail without push I wouldn't mind designing mine so that it would also fail in such a case.
   
  For a less "push-friendly" target though I'd rather think about giving my application an opportunity to fall back to polling in cases when push is't available for some reason.

Comment: Although it will eventually be developed on several different platforms, Android will be the first. Would you consider that platform "push-friendly"?

Comment: @user38214 hard to say. I did quick web search for _"android server push"_; overall impression is that it's not yet there. Though I could have missed something - better do your own study if you need to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Almost always you would have the mobile poll the server for new data.

The 'new data?' request can be a very small message and so reduces the power/data cost on the mobile  device, it handles the mobile being of/off/blocked/busy better and it scales to a large number of devices better than having to maintain an open connection to each device to push new data.

Comment: With polling, what is a reasonable time interval for udpates?

Comment: Depends on the application. How often does the data change and how often does the user need to know ?

Comment: The data can change at any time (anytime a form is submitted on the site). The goal would be that the mobile user gets notified as soon as possible.

Comment: @Josh that depends on how soon is necessary. Email can arrive at any time, but you don't need informing within a millisecond but you don't want to detect the next frame of a youtube video every 15mins!

Answer (score 0):

Normally network elements in a mobile data network do not allow establishing IP connections from the public internet. That anyhow would be rather difficult since a server on the internet does not know the mobile devices dynamic IP address.

It is possible to configure exceptions, i.e. equip mobile devices with fixed, non-NAT-ed IP addresses, in GSM network usually via a separate APN on the GGSN. An example would be machine-to-machine applications.

Talk to your mobile network operator. He usually will be interested only if there is a business case for him.